# What "solder" is used in 1000°F-1200°F applications?

Tags: soldering, temperature

[image: joint on mica backboard]

I got my hands on two decommissioned fuel cells, one of which I made functional. These are of the solid oxide type.

I decided to sacrifice the broken one to the reverse engineer gods. Inside the hot area, I found electrical contacts soldered with large blobs. Of some very white looking solder.

I can't for the life of me figure out what they were using to survive such a high temperature application; any ideas? I've never dealt with this high a temperature application before; nothing I've ever used would stand up to this and still be a reasonable conductor.
I'm guessing some platinum group metal, or specialized alloy (which explains why fuel cell tech is still expensive).

Fahrenheit/Celsius conversions:

- 1000 °F = 537.8 °C
- 1200 °F = 648.9 °C

Comment: It could be anything, but "brazing" is the general process you're looking for. It's basically soldering, but with materials of a higher melting point, closer to (but still below) the base metal's. Popular alloys include the copper-silver-zinc system (for copper, steel, etc.), but something specialized might've been used there.

Comment: Can you spot weld the parts?

Comment: @DDuck maybe, I added a picture

Comment: https://www.twi-global.com/technical-knowledge/published-papers/novel-joining-and-sealing-processes-for-solid-oxide-fuel-cells-july-2002

Comment: "nothing I've ever used would stand up to this and still be a reasonable conductor" – That makes me wonder how conductive copper is at 1200 F. (This isn't an answer, of course, since copper isn't white.)

Comment: Nice article @DDuck!

Answer (score 3):

1000F,  silver solder or brazing rod this is metalwork solder not electronics solder.

> platinum group metal,

whoah, aren't you talking 1200F, there's no need to go that extreme. 1200F is barely red hot. 1200C would be a different matter.